# Signed URL for google bucket does not match signature provided

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client, signing

I'm having an hard time working with google storage.

So I'm trying to make a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs), already have the client id (which is an email) and private key (as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts)) so:

STEP 1: [construct the string](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Construct-the-String)

```
function googleBuildConfigurationString($method, $expiration, $file, array $options = []) {
    $allowedMethods = ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'DELETE'];

    // initialize
    $method = strtoupper($method);
    $contentType = $options['Content_Type'];
    $contentMd5 = $options['Content_MD5'] ? base64_encode($options['Content_MD5']) : '';
    $headers = $options['Canonicalized_Extension_Headers'] ? $options['Canonicalized_Extension_Headers'] . PHP_EOL  : '';
    $file = $file ? $file : $options['Canonicalized_Resource'];

    // validate
    if(array_search($method, $allowedMethods) === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method '{$method}' is not allowed");
    }
    if(!$expiration) {
        throw new RuntimeException("An expiration date should be provided.");
    }

    return <<<TXT
    {$method}
    {$contentMd5}
    {$contentType}
    {$expiration}
    {$headers}{$file}
    TXT;
}
```

So far so good (I think), echoing the output it looks similar to the examples, so now to sign the string

STEP 2: [signing the string](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signing-Strings)
Initialy I was using *openssl_public_encrypt*, after searching around found that google-api-php-client has the Google_Signer_P12 (which actually uses *openssl_sign*), so the method looks like:

```
function googleSignString($certificatePath, $stringToSign) {
    return (new Google_Signer_P12(
        file_get_contents($certificatePath), 
        'notasecret'
    ))->sign($stringToSign);
}
```

And here I'm not sure if this is signing it correctly, finally building final url

STEP 3: [building the URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Assembling-the-URL)

```
function googleBuildSignedUrl($serviceEmail, $file, $expiration, $signature) {
    return "http://storage.googleapis.com{$file}"
    . "?GoogleAccessId={$serviceEmail}"
    . "&Expires={$expiration}"
    . "&Signature=" . urlencode($signature);
}
```

But the opening the URL in the browser will retrieve:

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
        The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
    </Message>
    <StringToSign>GET 1437470250 /example/video.mp4</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I've added a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MLoureiro/14503293c3cb2191e2f6) with the final script to be easier to read

So any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution, there was a bug on the expiration date where I was doing:

```
$expiration = (new DateTime())->modify('+3h')->getTimestamp();
```

So I've changed `h` to `hours` so that it works now, like:

```
$expiration = (new DateTime())->modify('+3hours')->getTimestamp();
```

But that didn't quite solved it, the actual missing part is that the `Google_Signer_P12::sign()` requires it to be encoded on base64, which is specified on the google docs:

> Google Cloud Storage expects the Base64 encoded signature in its APIs.

However I (wrongly) though that `Google_Signer_P12::sign()` already would do that, so after I understood that it was required I've changed the sign method to:

```
function googleSignString($certificatePath, $stringToSign)
{
  return base64_encode((new Google_Signer_P12(
    file_get_contents($certificatePath),
    'notasecret'
  ))->sign($stringToSign));
}
```

And it is working now!!!

I've also updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/MLoureiro/14503293c3cb2191e2f6) for anyone that wants to use it :)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the headers to work properly. I keep getting a signature error whenever I try to add one. Would you mind giving an example of adding a header in your answer?

Comment: If you take a look at [Sign Urls#Construct-the-String](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Construct-the-String)
It has the explanation where my headers (`$headers`) match their *Canonicalized_Extension_Headers*.There are several examples. 
The headers are optional, and it might be a requirement if you need to check some specific headers it might have to send.