# Force download on GCS via App Engine using Signed URL

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I get my file via:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';    
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$public_link = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://bucket/file.pdf", false);
```

If I go to `$public_link` in the browser, it shows the PDF inside the browser. I am trying to figure out how I can force the download of this file.

Google App Engine only has a 60 second timeout so I'm afraid the **serve** function wont work via GAE. Does anyone have any suggestions?

--

**EDIT**

Andrei Volga's previous answer in this post suggests I use a Signed URL with a `response-content-distribution` header.

So far, I am able to create a signed URL that successfully *shows* the file but I am not able to generate a signed url that has any sort of header at all aka create a signed URL that will force the download instead of just showing it.

This is what I have so far, most of which is [courtesy of mloureiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536066/signed-url-for-google-bucket-does-not-match-signature-provided).

```
function googleBuildConfigurationString($method, $expiration, $file, array $options = [])
{
    $allowedMethods = ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'DELETE'];
    // initialize
    $method = strtoupper($method);
    $contentType = $options['Content_Type'];
    $contentMd5 = $options['Content_MD5'] ? base64_encode($options['Content_MD5']) : '';
     $headers = $options['Canonicalized_Extension_Headers'] ? $options['Canonicalized_Extension_Headers'] . PHP_EOL : '';
     $file = $file ? $file : $options['Canonicalized_Resource'];

     // validate
    if(array_search($method, $allowedMethods) === false)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method '{$method}' is not allowed");
    }

    if(!$expiration)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("An expiration date should be provided.");
    }

    return <<<TXT
{$method}
{$contentMd5}
{$contentType}
{$expiration}
{$headers}{$file}
TXT;
    }

function googleSignString($p12FilePath, $string)
{
    $certs = [];

    if (!openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($p12FilePath), $certs, 'notasecret'))
    {
        echo "Unable to parse the p12 file. OpenSSL error: " . openssl_error_string(); exit();
    }

    $RSAPrivateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs["pkey"]);
    $signed = '';

    if(!openssl_sign( $string, $signed, $RSAPrivateKey, 'sha256' ))
    {
        error_log( 'openssl_sign failed!' );
        $signed = 'failed';
    }
    else $signed = base64_encode($signed);

    return $signed;
}

function googleBuildSignedUrl($serviceEmail, $file, $expiration, $signature)
{
    return "http://storage.googleapis.com{$file}" . "?GoogleAccessId={$serviceEmail}" . "&Expires={$expiration}" . "&Signature=" . urlencode($signature);
}

$serviceEmail = '<EMAIL>';
$p12FilePath = '../../path/to/cert.p12';
$expiration = (new DateTime())->modify('+3hours')->getTimestamp();
$bucket = 'bucket';
$fileToGet = 'picture.jpg';

$file = "/{$bucket}/{$fileToGet}";
$string = googleBuildConfigurationString('GET', $expiration, $file, array("Canonicalized_Extension_Headers" => ''));
$signedString = googleSignString($p12FilePath, $string);
$signedUrl = googleBuildSignedUrl($serviceEmail, $file, $expiration, $signedString);

echo $signedUrl;
```

Answer (score 2):

For small files you can use `serve` option instead of public URL with `save-as` option set to true. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools#method_getPublicUrl).

For large files you can use a [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs) with `response-content-disposition` parameter.

Comment: But if i'm serving a 1GB file, won't this exceed the 60 second limit?

Comment: It will not work for any file over 32MB - this is the limit for any response on App Engine. I will update my answer.

Comment: I am able to get a Signed URL successfully (check previous edit) but I can't figure out how to get the headers right. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a fragment from my Java code. You can adapt it: `.append("&response-content-disposition=")
.append(URLEncoder.encode("attachment;filename=" + "\"" + file.name + "\"", "UTF-8"))`

Comment: So basically, you need to add `&response-content-disposition=attachment;filename=` followed by a file name. I URL-encode it, but it's not necessary if you know the file name in advance and it's URL-safe (e.g. no spaces, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add and additional query string only.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#responsecontentdisposition

response-content-disposition

A query string parameter that allows content-disposition to be overridden for authenticated GET requests.

Valid Values    URL-encoded header to return instead of the content-disposition of the underlying object.

Example

```
?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22foo%22
```